# Android App ist running on Device in USB-Debug-Mode but not after APK-Install

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk, nfc

I am very new In Android Development and developed a "Time Stamp Clock - App" which reads NFC-Tags.

Everything fine, it is running on Device via USB-Debug-Mode without Errors as expected. When I build APK and install on the same Device, the installing is without errors, but after that, the open-button is grayed out and inactive and there is no desktop-icon to launch. In the APPS Overview it is displayed, but not able to open.

Can someone tell me, what can i do, to figure it out, what is going wrong there?

EDIT:

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.comidoszeiterfassung">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="30"></uses-sdk>

    <application
        android:name=".myGLOBAL"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ComidosZeiterfassung"
        tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.login.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.ComidosZeiterfassung.NoActionBar"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It is a simple structure in the app. LoginActivity as Start-Activity and a TabbedActivity for the NFC-Stuff.

Comment: Is there any error log Build tab in Android Studio when it tries to run your App? In addition, could you put your `manifest.xml` (anonymized if necessary)

Comment: @MrLeblond: There is the Manifest. No Errors on Building